# onSizeChanged execute only once

Tags: android-linearlayout

In my project, I add several views to a vertical extended `LinearLayout` (named MyLinearLayout) circularly, but after the loop, the method `onSizeChanged` finally executes, and it executes only once.

Why?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code your having an issue with.